# How to get the grouped product price with a quantity of 1 shild product in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a groupe product which is made by 2 shild product (1 real product + 1 "virtual" product which represent the cost of the reparation ).

Therefore, the customer has 2 possibilities :

- he can buy the real product to fix the problem by itself 
  or
- he can buy the bundle and he will buy the reparation set and automatically the real product, and it's my factory who will repare his problem

For example, the product cost 30€, and the reparation set cost 20€.

On the front end, it will be set :
"Starting at: 20€"

However, I supposed that the customer cannot buy this bundle with only one product. Therefore the price is 50€, and I would like that on the frontend the price is set to 50€.

I try to modify on my theme the file which is located on :
.../Catalog/Block/Product/View/price.phtml

I would like insert the following variable $simulationPrice :

`<span class="price" id="product-minimal-price-<?php echo $_id ?>
<?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
<?php "there I would like the price 50€" echo $simulationPrice  ?>

</span>`

To do that, I would like to perform the operation :

`<?php $_associatedProducts = $this->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $childProduct) { ?>
<?php $simulationPrice += $childProduct->getPrice() ?> 
<?php } ?>`

How can I do that ? I would like that the price = 1 real product * 1 quantity + 1 virtual product * 1 quantity.

If you have another method, it will be a pleasure to read your proposition.
I precise that I already modify the bundle and the customer can not modify the quantity which is set to 1 unit (1 real product + 1 virtual product), however he can modify the quantity in the basket...

If you have the solution about this code which doesn't work, it will be a pleasure.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Don't edit question titles to say "resolved" or "solved".

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution with this code :

```
$simulationPrice=0;  
$associatedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product); 
foreach ($associatedProducts as $childProduct) {  
    $quantityBackGround=$childProduct->getQty();
    $simulationPrice +=  $childProduct->getPrice() * $childProduct->getQty(); 
}
```

In fact the big problem was that I past my code into the following condition :

```
<?php if (!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
```

I didn't see the "!" in the condition....therefore it couldn't never work...